# How to design filters over normalized postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, filter, query-optimization

Currently, we have the following database design. We need to support multiple filters but with the heavy scale the queries are taking too long to run and it has become impossible to support new filtering options.

```
Table insights

string status
string id (pkey)
string title
string description
string owner
...
```

```
Table observation

string id
string source
string resource
string tags
string title
string description
...
```

```
Table insight_observation

string insight_id (fkey to id in insight table)
string observation_id (fkey to id in event table)
```

The insight table has m:n relationship with observation table and all the connections are
captured in insight_observation table.

Sample filters:

- Return all the insights where the insights status is `ACTIVE`
- Return all the insights where the observation source is in ['AWS', 'GCP']
- Return all the insights where
  insight_status = 'ACTIVE' AND
  insight_title contains 'i-123' AND
  insight_owner = `xyz@testme.com` AND
  observation_source is in ['AWS', 'AZURE'] AND
  observation_title contains `test alert`.

The query includes two inner joins and a lot of where conditions. With event table having more than 6M rows, the queries take a lot of time and APIs have become unresponsive.

Any other approach or suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the query execution plan:

Query & execution plan:

```
db=# explain (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) select distinct insightent0_.id as id1_3_, insightent0_.end_time as end_time4_3_, insightent0_.last_update_time as last_upd9_3_, insightent0_.org_id as org_id10_3_, insightent0_.severity as severit13_3_, insightent0_.start_time as start_t14_3_ from insight insightent0_
inner join insight_observations observatio1_ on insightent0_.id=observatio1_.insight_id
inner join observation observatio2_ on observatio1_.observation_id=observatio2_.observation_id
where insightent0_.org_id='ff24bwet-a665-9f20-x1m2-d8b083180153' and insightent0_.last_update_time>='2023-03-21T18:04:36.670Z' and insightent0_.last_update_time<='2023-03-01T18:04:36.670Z' and insightent0_.severity=3 and (observatio2_.source in ('AWS' , 'GCP')) order by insightent0_.last_update_time desc;
                                                                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=4520.20..4520.25 rows=4 width=204) (actual time=102.001..102.828 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1063
   ->  Sort  (cost=4520.20..4520.21 rows=4 width=204) (actual time=101.608..102.435 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: insightent0_.last_update_time DESC, insightent0_.id, insightent0_.end_time, insightent0_.start_time
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=1063
         ->  Gather  (cost=1001.23..4520.16 rows=4 width=204) (actual time=101.591..102.417 rows=0 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 1
               Workers Launched: 1
               Buffers: shared hit=1063
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.23..3519.76 rows=2 width=204) (actual time=11.017..11.019 rows=0 loops=2)
                     Buffers: shared hit=1063
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.54..1575.39 rows=268 width=317) (actual time=11.016..11.017 rows=0 loops=2)
                           Buffers: shared hit=1063
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on insight insightent0_  (cost=0.00..1307.96 rows=56 width=204) (actual time=11.015..11.015 rows=0 loops=2)
                                 Filter: ((last_update_time >= '2023-03-21 23:34:36.67+05:30'::timestamp with time zone) AND (last_update_time <= '2023-03-01 23:34:36.67+05:30'::timestamp with time zone) AND ((org_id)::text = 'ee04bfae-a665-4f20-a5b9-d8b043180252'::text) AND (severity = 3))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 10411
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1063
                           ->  Index Only Scan using insight_observations_pkey on insight_observations observatio1_  (cost=0.54..4.68 rows=10 width=231) (never executed)
                                 Index Cond: (insight_id = (insightent0_.id)::text)
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
                     ->  Index Scan using observation_pkey on observation observatio2_  (cost=0.68..7.26 rows=1 width=113) (never executed)
                           Index Cond: ((observation_id)::text = (observatio1_.observation_id)::text)
                           Filter: ((source)::text = ANY ('{AWS,GCP}'::text[]))
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=52
 Planning Time: 1.370 ms
 Execution Time: 102.926 ms
(28 rows)
```

Comment: Stick with the normalized design. If you create the correct indexes, the query should perform well. For a detailed analysis, you'd have to supply `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output for the slow query.

Comment: I have updated the query & execution plan. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You're asking for help optimizing "general filtering conditions". Sad to say, that's not how RDBMS query optimization works. It's common operational practice in fast-growing applications to examine your queries once a month or so, locate the slowest ones, and add indexes to support them.  By "slowest" I mean the queries where improved performance will help the most in delivering a quality experience to your users. Check this out:  https://use-the-index-luke.com

Comment: The current use case creates SQL dynamically as there are 8-10 filters and they can be combined dynamically. Only 2 columns are guaranteed to be there in all the queries but all other conditions can be added dynamically in the query. Creating index for all such column combination is not a feasible solution. I am open to totally different solution including using elasticSearch or other platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with the normalized design. The problem is not the join, but that you are missing an index to support the query. That would also happen in a denormalized data model.

Try this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON insight (org_id, severity, last_update_time);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is just one type of filtering condition. My ask is for general filtering conditions. There can be more for example (org_id, last_update_time, status) (org_id, last_update_time, impact) etc. Creating all kinds of index will not scale.

Comment: There is no way to speed up all kinds of queries, normalized or not. You have to restrict the queries you want to run, or you have to have bad performance. That is always the case.